# Openbravo Mysql db script syntax error

Tags: mysql, openbravo

I am unable to execute few sql queries in the mysql database from the scripts directory downloaded from the Mercurial repository of Openbravo.

Below is the query

```
INSERT INTO ROLES(ID, NAME, PERMISSIONS) VALUES('0', 'Administrator role', $FILE{com/openbravo/pos/templates/Role.Administrator.xml} );
```

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;**

I tried specifying the complete path, but still it displays syntax error.

```
INSERT INTO ROLES(ID, NAME, PERMISSIONS) VALUES('0', 'Administrator role', $FILE{/home/anand/Openbravo-POS/main/src-pos/com/openbravo/pos/templates/Role.Administrator.xml} );
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I have this on that query:

`INSERT INTO ROLES(ID, NAME, PERMISSIONS) VALUES('0', 'Administrator role', $FILE{/com/openbravo/pos/templates/Role.Administrator.xml} );`

Think you are missing `/` before `com/openbravo/...`

Sorry if it was too late